# Django REST Framework internal value

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a simple serializer with a date field (not ModelSerializer).

```
class MySerializer(Serializer):
    some_date = DateField()
```

I'm trying to access the date object after deserialization.

```
slz = MySerializer(data={"some_date": "2020-05-03"})
# I surely have a better error handling in my actual code
assert slz.is_valid()
some_extracted_date = slz.data["some_date"]
```

I would like my variable *some_extracted_date* to be a *datetime.date* instance.
But the value in the *MySerializer.data* dict is a string.

Is there a way to get this *datetime.date* instance ?

Comment: Try
`from dateutil import parser
my_dt_obj = parser.parse("your_string")`
If the first go doesn't work as you would expect (eg timezone) you may need to work with its format so it parses correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access data after validation using `validated_data`.

```
>>> from app.models import MySerializer
>>> slz = MySerializer(data={"some_date": "2020-05-03"})
>>> slz.is_valid(True)
True
>>> slz.data
{'some_date': '2020-05-03'}
>>> slz.validated_data
OrderedDict([('some_date', datetime.date(2020, 5, 3))])
>>> slz.validated_data['some_date']
datetime.date(2020, 5, 3)
```